# How to push array of array in codeigniter?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I am declare my array as public

```
class Doctor extends CI_Controller {

    public $prescription_drug = array();

.....

}
```

I need array like following

```
Array
(
        [0] => Array
        (
            [drugdoze] => 8
            [drugname] => 80
            [drugsize] => 5
            [drugtype] => 1
            [duration] => 
            [rx_duration] => 2
            [rx_instruction] => 3
            [rx_special_note] => “test 1”
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [drugdoze] => 4
            [drugname] => 10
            [drugsize] => 5
            [drugtype] => 3
            [duration] => 1
            [rx_duration] => 2
            [rx_instruction] => 3
            [rx_special_note] => “test 2”
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [drugdoze] => 1
            [drugname] => 13
            [drugsize] => 5
            [drugtype] => 3
            [duration] => 1
            [rx_duration] => 2
            [rx_instruction] => 3
            [rx_special_note] => “test 3”
        )

)


How can I append following array with
[3] => Array
        (
            [drugdoze] => 1
            [drugname] => 13
            [drugsize] => 5
            [drugtype] => 3
            [duration] => 1
            [rx_duration] => 2
            [rx_instruction] => 3
            [rx_special_note] => “test 3”
        )
```

I have a public function

```
public function prescription_selected_drug_session()
    {

    $prescription_data= array(
                'drugdoze' => $this->input->post("drugdoze"),
                'drugname'=> $this->input->post("drugname"),
                'drugsize' => $this->input->post("drugsize"),
                'drugtype' =>$this->input->post("drugtype"),
                'duration'=> $this->input->post("duration"),
                'rx_duration' => $this->input->post("rx_duration"),
                'rx_instruction'=>$this->input->post("rx_instruction"),
                'rx_special_note' => $this->input->post("rx_special_note")
                );


    array_push($this->prescription_drug,$prescription_data);

}
```

I call the function using ajax. But the value of $this->prescription_drug is overwriten every times not appended.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Php is stateless. Every ajax request creates a new instance of `Doctor`.

You will need to persist the data in session or database, or aggregate client side

Comment: if($this->session->userdata('prescription_selected_drug'))
  {  
  $temp_array =  $this->session->userdata('prescription_selected_drug');
        array_push($temp_array, $prescription_data);
        $this->session->set_userdata('prescription_selected_drug', $temp_array);  
  }
  else
  {
   
  $this->session->set_userdata("prescription_selected_drug",$prescription_data);
  }

Comment: but now array became Array
(
    [drugdoze] => 2
    [drugname] => 155
    [drugsize] => 25
    [drugtype] => 1
    [duration] => 1
    [rx_duration] => 1
    [rx_instruction] => 1
    [rx_special_note] => this is test1
    [0] => Array
        (
            [drugdoze] => 2
            [drugname] => 303
            [drugsize] => 3
            [drugtype] => 1
            [duration] => 1
            [rx_duration] => 2
            [rx_instruction] => 1
            [rx_special_note] => this is test2
        )

)